# Using HtmlWebpackPlugin with CommonsChunkPlugin throws an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`

Tags: webpack, webpack-2, html-webpack-plugin, commonschunkplugin

When I use both [HtmlWebpackPlugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-webpack-plugin) and [CommonsChunkPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/commons-chunk-plugin/) in a webpack config,
I get an error saying `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined`.

[image]

Some people say that `minChunks` has not to be `callback` but `Infinity`.
But I just wanna use callback to split all third party libs from `node_modules`.

I know this issue has similar questions but none of them are helpful to me.

Here is my [webpack.config.js](https://github.com/RyoIkarashi/webpack-static-pages-boilerplate/blob/master/webpack.config.js)

Thanks a lot in advance.

Here is the versions I use below.

- node v6.9.5
- webpack v2.2.1

Comment: provided `webpack.config.js` does not produce such error. cannot reproduce

Comment: @AdamWolski Could you please share the error you got?
I cloned my own repo and run `yarn` and `yarn start`. I got the same error I'd got before.
Anyway thank you for taking your precious time!

Comment: there is no error, everything works fine